# How do I calculate the time difference between a units dispatch time and enroute time when times are in the same column

Tags: sql

Can someone help me with an SQL issue.  In an SQL table, how do I calculate each units time difference between that units dispatch time and en-route time for each Case Id (call)

```
Case Id     Nature      TransType   Description TimeStamp           Unit
15001925    Fire Alarm  D           Dispatched  10/01/2015 12:32:34 E99
15001925    Fire Alarm  E           En-route    10/01/2015 12:33:07 E99
15001925    Fire Alarm  D           Dispatched  10/01/2015 12:32:34 E98
15001925    Fire Alarm  E           En-route    10/01/2015 12:33:37 E98
15001926    Car Fire    D           Dispatched  10/01/2015 12:44:24 T98
15001926    Car Fire    E           En-route    10/01/2015 12:45:27 T98
```

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Describe the calculation you want.  (3) Show the results you want from your query.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I think he just wants the difference in time between dispatch and en-route for each Case Id/Unit combination.  But maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes - that is what I need the enroute minus dispatch for each unit on each case Id.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT "Case Id",
       Unit,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Description = 'En-route'   THEN TimeStamp ELSE 0 END) -
       MAX(CASE WHEN Description = 'Dispatched' THEN TimeStamp ELSE 0 END) AS timeDiff
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY "Case Id", Unit
```